# Unable to use Appbar in Flutter Adaptive Scaffold At Certain Breakpoints

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried the example used in [flutter_adaptive_scaffold](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_adaptive_scaffold) but with an `Appbar` widget and setting `useDrawer` to true . The widget only appears when I resize to a mobile size (I'm running this on web)

```dart
AdaptiveScaffold(
      // An option to override the default breakpoints used for small, medium,
      // and large.
      smallBreakpoint: const WidthPlatformBreakpoint(end: 700),
      mediumBreakpoint: const WidthPlatformBreakpoint(begin: 700, end: 1000),
      largeBreakpoint: const WidthPlatformBreakpoint(begin: 1000),
      useDrawer: true,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("My App")),
      selectedIndex: _selectedTab,
      onSelectedIndexChange: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedTab = index;
        });
      },
      destinations: const <NavigationDestination>[
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.inbox_outlined),
          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.inbox),
          label: 'Inbox',
        ),
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.article_outlined),
          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.article),
          label: 'Articles',
        ),
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.chat_outlined),
          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.chat),
          label: 'Chat',
        ),
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.video_call_outlined),
          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.video_call),
          label: 'Video',
        ),
        NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Inbox',
        ),
      ],
      body: (_) => GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 2, children: children),
      smallBody: (_) => ListView.builder(
        itemCount: children.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, int idx) => children[idx],
      ),
      // Define a default secondaryBody.
      secondaryBody: (_) => Container(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 234, 158, 192),
      ),
      // Override the default secondaryBody during the smallBreakpoint to be
      // empty. Must use AdaptiveScaffold.emptyBuilder to ensure it is properly
      // overridden.
      smallSecondaryBody: AdaptiveScaffold.emptyBuilder,
    )
```

I've tried looking for an option to make the `Appbar` always visible but I couldn't find it

Comment: I've noticed this issue too and probably the best bet is to look into using `AdaptiveLayout`, which is a lower level widget in the same package.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set appBarBreakpoint. Begin at 0 to always show, or set the min or max size you want to show it:

```
 appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("My App")),
 appBarBreakpoint: const WidthPlatformBreakpoint(begin: 0),
```